# A user should just be destroyed network-wide automatically if it has no upvoted content and is destroyed on two independent sites by mods already

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

We get the occasional network spammer who creates accounts on several sites to post their spam.

At the moment when a moderator on site A spots this they have to do one of the following:

1. Call the moderators from the other sites and let them know so that they can destroy their accounts too.
2. Find a community team member to let them know so that the account can be destroyed everywhere in one go.

in addition to flagging any posts on the other sites as spam to help remove them from the home page as quickly as possible.

Neither approach is ideal.

The first requires each site's moderators to be contacted in turn and to be around, the second relies on there being a community team member around to act, or for the moderator to remember to suspend the account for 30 or 365 days and use the "contact cm" option on the account.

It would be far better if this process could be automated. Then when the mods on the second site react to the spam flags and destroy the account on their site, this would initiate the network wide destruction of accounts. If that's deemed too extreme then the destruction of the second account raises a "flag" on their network profile for the CM's to investigate.

This would mean that there'd be no requirement to coordinate all the moderators on the various sites or with the community team (who have better things to be doing).

Comment: [This user](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/64078/user59217) makes a rather good example of this, I suspect.  Can't prove it for EL&U, but he was certainly spamming Arqade.

Comment: Yes, that user did spam ELU, and it looks like a community manager was called upon to deal with him.

Comment: I'm upvoting on the basis that "2 other accounts destroyed for spamming" will definitely be spam and not spam-ish. I guess mods rarely destroy unless it defo needs nuking, and then yes, why not do all accounts?