# Raise a Community Manager message when an account is destroyed for spamming

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, spam

This is a follow-up to this, unanswered, question:

[A user should just be destroyed network-wide automatically if it has no upvoted content and is destroyed on two independent sites by mods already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211817/a-user-should-just-be-destroyed-network-wide-automatically-if-it-has-no-upvoted)

When you come across a spammer's account that has other accounts on the network, there's no easy way to let other site moderators know that they have a potential spammer.

You need to either ping each site's mods individually which is inefficient as soon as there are more than a handful of linked accounts or remember to raise a CM message and suspend the user rather than just destroying the user.

Unfortunately, destroying the account as a spammer is by far the most efficient thing I can do to limit their ability to post spam on my site, so I forget the more long winded process.

What I propose is that when an account is destroyed on one site and it has other accounts elsewhere on the network a CM message is raised for those other accounts so that the community managers can review the action and **if necessary** do a sweep up and remove all the accounts in one go rather than having to contact each site's mods individually. This will mean I no longer have to contact the other site's moderators and they don't have to act on potentially incomplete evidence.

Comment: I am not sure CM is the right place to escalate to, though I agree that better visibility would be welcome.

Comment: @tripleee - the alternative (other than automatically nuking all the accounts) is to send a message to all mods on all the other sites, which seems a lot more inefficient to me.

Comment: Well, an alternative would be to raise a flag on each site. We occationally manually raise a cm flag but its also not scalable.

Comment: Perhaps, there should be a limit when a flag is raised? 5 network accounts, we'll take care, less than 5, ping the other mods in TL.

Comment: Or the other way around, float a friendly red balloon on the account's profile image and eventually maybe develop a separate tool to find these?

Comment: which a flag/annotation is ;p

Comment: As a moderator, I'm not sure I should be taking any action against a user who's done nothing on my site anyway.  That kind of decision feels like it's above my pay grade.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - hence the flag to the CMs. There'd be no automatic action. The CM would review it and decide whether all the accounts should be removed or not.

Comment: Right, this would be much better.  I was just pointing out one way in which the current approach doesn't work, in addition to the hassles you pointed out.