# Auto suspend the user network-wide if their accounts have been destroyed on a certain number (e.g. 3) of sites

Tags: feature-request, status-review, spam, network-wide-suspension, account-destruction

*Possibly related; might be an extension or alternative to: [A user should just be destroyed network-wide automatically if it has no upvoted content and is destroyed on two independent sites by mods already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211817/241919.)*

---

As already explained in the linked question, spammers tend to create many accounts, then a mod from each site may destroy their account. Destroying their account will also automatically impose an account suspension, but only to that site.

*This feature request expands the site suspension to the network-wide suspension if the user has been destroyed on a few sites, e.g. **3 different sites.***

What I think the difference from the linked request is the timing; i.e. when they only have a few accounts but are destroyed network-wide, then they can still create a new account on the rest of the network and not suspended. This request intends to *prevent future active spamming on other sites* instead of cleaning passive profile spam (which the linked request may be more efficient for this).

Comment: I'd be interested to know how often the same spammer account spams 4+ sites to see how impactful this would be

Comment: I think this is a good idea, although I'd suggest a provision that the destroying would have to be done by different mods across the sites as a sanity check, since there are a number of us modding 3+ sites. It would be nice to make 100% sure that multiple people need to push a button before suspending network-wide -- to prevent both mistakes and abuse.

Comment: @MissSkooterstandswPalestine Often enough that it's far from a unique situation, but it would be difficult to get proper statistics on this.